# Is there a setting to have the Activities screen timeout and go away?

Tags: gnome

When you press the Windows key on the keyboard the Activities screen comes up.  If you press the Esc key, it goes away.

I've noticed that if there is a display change like HDMI disconnect and reconnect (or handshake change), sometimes this screen comes up and will not go away by itself.  Running as a kiosk mode this is not preferable.

Is there a way to have this timeout and return to the previous desktop?

Is this screen called Activities? (for google searching/indexing)

Is there a way to disable this screen all together?  We do not need multiple desktops/workspaces.

EDIT1: Installing 'xdotool' and performing the command below will send Escape key to the Gnome desktop.  This is my first workaround discovered I could build into a script.

`DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key Escape`

Screenshot:

[image: Activities Screenshot]